# Is it possible to establish secured WS connection (TLS/SSL) from GAE to external endpoint?

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine

I'm building a Web App and I'm targeting Google App Engine hosting.

My backend has to access a SOAP Web-Service. If the endpoint is over TLS/SSL, can I still use Google App Engine? This is what I found:

[Build a SOAP Server and a SOAP Client on Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/soap.html#cl)

In this case I'll probably need to import a .X509 certificate (keystore and truststore) from the SOAP service provider to establish a secured node. Has anyone tried to establish a secured connection?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make HTTPS connections on App Engine. It's not currently possible to supply your own certificate, however, so the endpoint will have to be using an HTTPS certificate signed by a known CA.